# Why we are avoid Magic Numbers or Constants from Program and use macro?

Tags: c

here C programming Guidelines and coding standards says we have to avoid magic numbers from program and use macro  for magic numbers

In Macro it will take more time to evaluate as compare to Constants so performance is more better in magic numbers or constants.

for Example

```
for(i=0;i<255;i++)
{

}
```

We use this

```
#define MAX 255

for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{

}
```

Second one is take more time compare to first one so why we prefer second one as per coding standards.

Comment: "In Macro it will take more time to evaluate as compare to Constants" No, it won't. Unless you are speaking of compilation time, which may be fractionally longer.

Comment: 1: magic numbers don't convey author's meaning, 2: magic numbers, when duplicated, take more time to change

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: In addition to only changing it in one place as the answers state the `#define` is also better documentation.  `MAX` isn't very descriptive but what if it were `MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS` or `NUMBER_OF_INPUT_PINS`, i.e. something with meaning in your domain.  This makes the code much clearer than simply having `255` in the loop condition.

Comment: Just to one sub question you raise in your comment: I can confirm that "fast is Contacts na." That's just the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using a macro constant doesn't take more time. the `#define` is a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) instruction, so in the binary code, **the two pieces of code will compile to the same thing!**

However, we avoid using 'magic numbers' for reasons of [maintainability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability), assume you have many loops and arrays of the same size, if this size changes in the future, you will need to search the code and change it everywhere, [and only it!] while if you use a preprocessor command, you will need to change only it [the preprocessor command].

Answer (score 2):

It's about mainatenance, not performance. Any time you duplicate the same number twice for the same purpose, it should go in a variable, macro, or const.  Read up on DRY; duplication of code or values greatly increases the chance of future bugs.

And I believe macros are expanded at compile-time, not runtime, so there is no performance dowside at all. Even with a const there isn't a measurable difference - less than a single cycle, I believe.

Also look up Premature Optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Both pieces of code will be compiled to the same thing.  Instances of `MAX` are substitued with 255 when the pre-processor runs, so the compiler is working with the exact same code.

The benefit to using the `#define` or a constant is that if the value is used in multiple places and has to be chaned for some reason, it's trivial to change the `#define` instead of finding all places the value is being used and changing them.

Answer (score 0):

- It documents the code (a meaningful constant name gives reader an idea why 255 and not 254, what does the number mean)
- When number is used multiple times, it greatly helps to avoid errors of changing it in one place and forgetting to change in another
- It is not slower at all (by the way)

Answer (score 0):

The second is preferable as it gives meaning when reading the loop. For somebody coming in and maintaining the code you wrote in the first example, the obvious question is "why 255"? What does that mean, what will happen if I modify it? It's far clearer to give this value a name, and #define it. If that same number is used throughout the program, it only needs to be modified in one place.

As for the cost of doing this, it's tiny. At compilation time, all instances of MAX will be replaced with 255. At runtime, there is no cost.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a C program, the program is first processed by the C preprocessor. It process all the `#foo` stuff in your program and replaces macros. By the time the *actual* compiler sees the code, your macros have been replaced with values.

So if you feed your second code snippet to the compiler, the *actual* C compiler will see the exact same thing as in your first code snippet. This means that using a macro instead of a value *does not* slow down your program.

The idea about using macros (or constants) is to have names for your numbers that may make sense to a human.

Consider your program supports three bicycles (or whatever, doesn't matter). You would need to write `3` in a lot of places (like you wrote 255 in your `for` loop). But a month later, you might not remember the *meaning* of a 3 any more when you see it. If you instead have:

```
#define MAX_BICYCLES 3
```

and then use `MAX_BICYCLES` everywhere the intention becomes clearer. Better yet, once your app should support, say, 5 bicycles it might be as easy as changing that one macro. You do not have to remember in which places to change a `3` to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a number change or the numbers were just plain wrong how would you know?
Instead of magic numbers use a real name that means something.
 You can use #define or constants or enums as names.
 Which one is a design choice.
 For example:

```
 #define   PRESIDENT_WENT_CRAZY  (22)
const int WE_GOOFED= 19;
enum  {
  THEY_DIDNT_PAY= 16
};

if      (PRESIDENT_WENT_CRAZY == foo) { start_thermo_nuclear_war(); }
else if (WE_GOOFED            == foo) { refund_lotso_money(); }
else if (THEY_DIDNT_PAY       == foo) { infinite_loop(); }
else                                  { happy_days_i_know_why_im_here(); }
```

Now isn't that better?
 The const and enum options are preferable because when debugging the debugger has enough information to display both the value and the label.